# how to parse parameters from graph in Azure AD B2C custom policy?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

this is a very simple question. I have the following response from a rest api:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(lastPasswordChangeDateTime)",
    "value": [
        {
            "lastPasswordChangeDateTime": "2023-05-17T10:54:04Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

At the moment, I am able to talk to the API but unable to parse the data.
I have tried the following:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="test" PartnerClaimType="value.0.lastPasswordChangeDateTime"/>

<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="test" PartnerClaimType="value"/> this one errors

<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="test" PartnerClaimType="lastPasswordChangeDateTime"/>

        <ClaimType Id="test">
            <DisplayName>testing purposes</DisplayName>
            <DataType>dateTime</DataType>
            <AdminHelpText>test</AdminHelpText>
        </ClaimType>
```

I have managed to get the following string `"{\r\n  \"lastPasswordChangeDateTime\": \"2023-05-17T10:54:04Z\"\r\n}"`
Even if I manage to get the date, that would be a string with claims transformation, how do I get the dateTime so I can use the proper claims transformations?